# Using the FromBody attribute

Tags: c#, post, restsharp

I'm trying to use the `FromBody` attribute, however, it doesn't work. Here's my method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SetMap([FromBody]int mapId)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Map: {0}", mapId);
}
```

I'm adding a parameter to my request called `mapId` with the value of `10000`, however, the output is always `0`. Why's that happening?

I'm sending the `POST` request using `RestSharp` like so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8999");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);



            request.Resource = "Character/SetMap";
            request.AddParameter("mapId", 1000);

            var response = client.Execute(request);

            var data = response.Content;

            MessageBox.Show("Online: " + data + ".");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client code is sending this request message:

```
POST /Character/SetMap?mapId=1000
Body: [empty]
```

Your server code is expecting a request message like this:

```
POST /Character/SetMap
Body: 1000
```

You should switch your `[FromBody]` attribute to `[FromUri]` so that your client and server match.